# Send Request Funcion

Tags: ros, ros2, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The add_two_ints_client.cpp file in the ros2/demos repository has the following send request function.

[image: image description]

Is there a way to make this send request function generic for other services I have created?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330056/send-request-funcion/) by [mikepark93](https://answers.ros.org/users/44418/mikepark93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-08-05**:
Please don't use an image to display text/code. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste the text from the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can use a template.

```
template<typename ServiceT>
typename ServiceT::Response::SharedPtr send_request(
  rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node,
  typename rclcpp::Client<ServiceT>::SharedPtr client,
  typename ServiceT::Request::SharedPtr request)
{
  auto result = client->async_send_request(request);
  // Wait for the result.
  if (rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(node, result) ==
    rclcpp::executor::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
  {
    return result.get();
  } else {
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
  using ServiceT1 = ....
  using ServiceT2 = ....

  auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("client_node");
  auto client_1 = node->create_client<ServiceT1>("my_service_1_name");
  auto client_2 = node->create_client<ServiceT2>("my_service_2_name");

  auto request_1 = std::make_shared<ServiceT1::Request>();
  auto result_1 = send_request<ServiceT1>(node, client_1, request_1);

  auto request_2 = std::make_shared<ServiceT2::Request>();
  auto result_2 = send_request<ServiceT2>(node, client_2, request_2);
```

P.S. In ROS2 this is not the recommended style for creating nodes. You should create a class that extends `rclcpp::Node` and define the `send_request` function and the clients as members of this class.

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepark93](https://answers.ros.org/users/44418/mikepark93/) on 2019-08-05**:
When I try building, I get an error saying the following:

```
error: ‘rclcpp::Client<ServiceT>::SharedPtr’ is not a type rclcpp::Client<ServiceT>::SharedPtr client
```

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-08-05**:
How have you defined `servicet` in your code?

**Comment by [mikepark93](https://answers.ros.org/users/44418/mikepark93/) on 2019-08-05**:
This was how I defined it before:

```
rclcpp::Client<orion_sensor::srv::SetFocus>::SharedPtr client
```

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-08-05**:
So you should use `using ServiceT = orion_sensor::srv::SetFocus;`.
Or you remove this line and you just keep using `orion_sensor::srv::SetFocus` as before, changing only the `send_request` function and adding the template parameter when calling it i.e. `send_request<orion_sensor::srv::SetFocus>(...)`